# Does anyone remember this old "trapped in a video game" anime?

Tags: story-identification, anime

The animation looked like an Anime. It was about this kid that is playing this video game, where some dinosaur monsters are chasing a girl. If I'm not mistaken, he's playing as the monsters, but then he gets sucked into the video game and realizes the girl is on the side of good or something. He tries protecting her, and then he makes friends with a monster pet of some sort, whom he names after a dish his mom makes (I forgot the name of the dish/monster) because the monster looks very similar (it's white, with a green leaf/something on top of it).

As a specific, the boy is NOT permanently trapped in the game. He can get out of the game periodically, but every time he plays it, he travels to the dimension (and a stock footage of him getting sucked in plays).

I remember watching two or three episodes as a kid, but then they stopped airing it. It's probably from the 90s or early 2000s at most. I'm pretty sure it was an anime, but then again, Martin Mystery had "Animesque" animation too, so maybe it's American? I dunno.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_Art_Online?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_Horizon?

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/14765/Ixion_Saga_DT?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btooom!?

Comment: Obvious one here: Captain N The Gamemaster.

Comment: @Valorum those anime are certainly not from the 90s or early 2000s

Answer (score 9):

This is *[Monster Rancher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Rancher_(anime))*. 100%
The dish you're talking about is Mochi, which becomes the name of the pink (not white) monster.

However, the boy cannot get out of the game. I believe he's stuck until he defeats 'the evil' or some other requirement is met.
The whole premise is that they take discs to a shrine/summoning area, with hopes of releasing a monster known as the Pheonix.

Comment: probably OP remember him getting in and out because that stock footage was part of the opening sequence, but yeah, he was trapped there